# How to configure Windows Azure Web Role instances for a static HTML fall back site

Tags: azure, failover, fallback

I'm hosting a high traffic website on Windows Azure, i.e. 2 large Web Role instances to ensure 99.95% availability.

However, in extreme circumstances when these instances go down (it could be due to application issues / stress), how would I configure another 3rd Web Role instance (this would have static content- its a Fall-back static site) so that it automatically serves in-coming requests.

Please note that I only need automatic redirection/activation of 3rd Role when both instances fail.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [Azure Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx) and a small webrole in a different datacenter or a service like DynDNS to monitor the endpoints and provide failover to another site hosted outside of Azure.

Azure Traffic Manager won't redirect to a non-Azure hosted site.